# jQuery: Añadir botón a formulario

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Tenía una estructura HTML, que he tenido que borrar porque necesito que jQuery la dibuje de forma dinámica, tal que así:

```
<form class="d-inline" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php">

    (<button class="modal-ano boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio"></button>)

</form>
```

En realidad esto iba dentro del `body` de un modal Bootstrap junto a otros elementos HTML.

Con los datos provenientes vía `.ajax()` de un JSON (`respuesta`) le daba valor y nombre al botón dentro de un bucle `for` (porque en realidad puedo necesitar pintar varios botones y no uno solo):

```
$('.modal-ano').text(respuesta[i].ano);
$('.modal-ano').val(respuesta[i].ano);
```

Es decir, el botón aparecía con este aspecto, en caso de que fuera el año 1996:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer clic en él, te llevaba a `recopilatorios.php` con información específica para el año 1996, proveniente de mi base de datos.

Bien, he sustituido el formulario por la siguiente variable:

```
var formulario = $(document.createElement('form'))
                        .addClass('d-inline')
                        .attr('method', 'post').attr('action', 'index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php')
                        .html(boton)
                        .appendTo('.cuerpo-subestilo');
```

El formulario se agrega igualmente al `body` del modal, de `class = "cuerpo-subestilo"`.

A su vez también he definido una variable botón, que pretendo insertar dentro del formulario:

```
var boton = $(document.createElement('span'))
                        .addClass('boton-enlace')
                        .attr('role', 'link').attr('name', 'recopilatorio')
                        .text(` (${respuesta[i].ano})`)
                        .val(respuesta[i].ano);
```

De ahí que la variable formulario tenga `.html(boton)`, pero esto no funciona: al activar el modal aparece el botón con el aspecto esperable, pero no te lleva a ningún lado.

¿Cómo podría replicar exactamente la estructura que tenía dibujada estáticamente en HTML con variables y jQuery?

EDICIÓN: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que el botón lo he creado como un elemento `span` en vez de como un `button`; así, imposible que funcione...

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa es que en ningún momento le pasas el año al formulario que creas dinamicamente, si pintas el texto visible, te propongo 3 formas

**primera forma**

Creas el formulario y pasas el valor por la ruta

```
<form class="d-inline" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php&ano=1996">
    (<button class="modal-ano boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio"></button>)
</form>
```

**segunda forma** `recomendado para post`

Debes crear tu formulario que contenga un `input` no `button` y quedaria asi

```
<form class="d-inline" method="post" action="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{ano}" name="{atributo}"/>
</form>
```

**tercera forma** `si el año es tu unico parámetro`

cambia tu `clase controlador` a `GET` y unicamente creas

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?fichero=recopilatorios.php&ano={ano}">{ano}</a>
```

Comment: Había una errata en el código, y el botón era un `span` en vez de un `button`; por eso no funcionaba...

Comment: usando un input de tipo `submit`, funciona ademas envia su parametro